# Why always i get undefined? i am using scroll to load my datas

Tags: reactjs

i am using useEffect to linking the event scroll

```
const myHandle = async () => {
    if (
        Math.ceil(window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop) !== document.documentElement.offsetHeight ||
        isFetching
    )
        return;
    console.log(schools) // here is undefined
  };

 useEffect(() => {
     setSchools({
          alertList: [1,2,3],
        })
      window.addEventListener('scroll', myHandle);
 }
```

i am getting always undefined, what is the problem?

Comment: Because the callback of the addEventListener has its own context which is `schools` is undefined in that context

Comment: @Dilshan how can i solved?can you writte your answer please!

Comment: Are you sure your code works correct ? I think your `useState`'s value is undefined. and also make sure to remove the eventlistener from useEffect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the validity of your short sample but if you want it in proper React Hook style, then

```
const myHandle = useCallback(async () => {
    if (
        Math.ceil(window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop) !== document.documentElement.offsetHeight ||
        isFetching
    )
        return;
    console.log(schools); // here is undefined
  }, [isFetching, schools]);

 useEffect(() => {
     setSchools({
          alertList: [1,2,3],
        });
      window.addEventListener('scroll', myHandle);
      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', myHandle);
      }
 }, [myHandle])
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you define the state of school which is undefined here is a simple hook you can check
I am not getting undefine

```
import React from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
const [schools, setSchools] = React.useState({});//school state
const [isFetching,setisFetching]=React.useState(false); //isFetching state
const myHandle = async () => {
if (
  Math.ceil(window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop) !==
    document.documentElement.offsetHeight || isFetching
  
) {
  console.log(schools, "this is data"); // here is
  return;
} else {
  console.log(schools, "this is data"); // here is
}
};

useEffect(() => {
setSchools({
  alertList: [1, 2, 3]
});
window.addEventListener("scroll", myHandle());
}, []);
 return (
 <div className="App">
 
 </div>
 );
 }
```

[This is console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wf97P.png)